# Not able to click on AXImage

Tags: xamarin, automation, appium, xamarin.mac

I am working on a Xamarin.Mac Application. Where I want to click an image using Appium test automation.

The driver doesn't seem to be able to click on an AXImage. Is there any known workarounds for clicking on them?

Comment: Seems to already been asked here: https://discuss.appium.io/t/appiumformac-not-clicking/31076 What have you tried? What errors are you seeing? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Added the capabilty **MobileCapabilityType.FORCE_MJSONWP** as **true** and it worked for me. This is a work around in java client.
[[W3C] Does not support sending keys to active element for Mac](https://github.com/appium/appium-for-mac/issues/80)